# Photoshop CS3 > Marquee Tool > Modify > Contract problem?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, tools, selections, marquee-tool

Very strange.... 
The **circular Selection** I Made by using **Marquee Tool** is no longer good once it's contracted by using **SELECT | MODIFY | CONTRACT** ....

In conclusion, if i made **CONTRACTION** to make the circular smaller, then the ugly shape become appeared clearly.

check out my preview image, ... 
[image]

How to solve it anyway?

Comment: Duplicate your shape on a new layer, maybe it will look better. It's "normal" that the contraction amplifies "corners" of  irregular circles like this one. Unfortunately, I have no answer how to improve this by using the contraction.

Comment: @go-meek Posted by the same user, even!